# Discrepancy between Matlab and R image processing output

Tags: r, matlab, image-processing, r-raster

I am trying to calculate the mean of an image (single band) containing Inf. I have done it in both R and Matlab. But the outputs are different. Can anyone guide me what am I doing wrong? The codes are provided below

**Matlab code**

```
I = imread('peppers.png');

% Extract color channels as single data type
R = single(I(:,:,1)); % Red channel
G = single(I(:,:,2)); % Green channel
B = single(I(:,:,3)); % Blue channel

%Index calculation
Hue_index = (2*R-G-B)./(G-B);

%Mean calculation after ignoring inf
mean_HI = mean(reshape(~isinf(Hue_index), [], 1));

% mean_HI = 0.9947

imwrite(I, 'peppers.png'); %Saving the image for using it in R
```

**R code**

```
library(raster)

#Load the image, Use stack function to read in all bands
r <- stack("peppers.png")

#Now read the individual bands from the stack
R=r[[1]]
G=r[[2]]
B=r[[3]]

#Index calculation
Hue_index = (2*R-G-B)/(G-B)
Hue_index
#> class      : RasterLayer 
#> dimensions : 384, 512, 196608  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
#> resolution : 1, 1  (x, y)
#> extent     : 0, 512, 0, 384  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#> crs        : NA 
#> source     : memory
#> names      : layer 
#> values     : -Inf, Inf  (min, max)

#Replaces inf or -inf with NA
is.na(Hue_index) <- sapply(Hue_index, is.infinite)

#Raster to dataframe conversion
HI_df  = raster::as.data.frame(Hue_index, xy = TRUE)

#Mean calculation of the dataframe
HI_mean <- raster::mean(HI_df$layer, na.rm=T)
HI_mean 
#> [1] -1.516576
```

As you can see from `Hue_index`, it contains -Inf and Inf and the outputs from Matlab (0.9947) and R (-1.516576) are different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know R, but I can see that in your Matlab code you're calculating the average of `~isinf(Hue_index)`, which is not the average of `Hue_index` after removing the Inf values.

In fact, calculating `mean(Hue_index(~isinf(Hue_index)), 'all', 'omitnan') = -1.5165759`, which is pretty close to the value you have from R.

Now, whether you want to calculate the mean of `~isinf(Hue_index)` (which is a matrix with only 1s and 0s depending on whether `Hue_index` is Inf or not) or the mean of `Hue_index(~isinf(Hue_index))` is up to you.

EDIT:

Here the complete code, where the only change is the call to mean. The code runs fine for me (MATLAB R2019a on Windows 10).

```
I = imread('peppers.png');

% Extract color channels as single data type
R = single(I(:,:,1)); % Red channel
G = single(I(:,:,2)); % Green channel
B = single(I(:,:,3)); % Blue channel

%Index calculation
Hue_index = (2*R-G-B)./(G-B);

%Mean calculation after ignoring inf
mean_HI = mean(Hue_index(~isinf(Hue_index)), 'all', 'omitnan');
```

Comment: Running `mean(Hue_index(~isinf(Hue_index)), 'all', 'omitnan');` returns me following error
```Error using sum
The dimension input to SUM must be numeric.

Error in mean (line 82)
    y = sum(x,dim,flag)/size(x,dim);``` I want to calculate mean after removing inf.

Comment: It will be great if you provide the complete code.

Comment: If you still have an error, that's weird. Try reshaping your Hue_index, `mean_HI = mean(reshape(Hue_index(~isinf(Hue_index)), [], 1), 'omitnan');`

Comment: Actually, I am using MATLAB R2014b on Windows 10.

Comment: Then I guess the 'all' flag was not yet implemented, and Matlab is trying to read the flag 'all' as the field 'dim' which only accepts numeric values. Reshaping the array in the call for mean like in my previous comment should work then.